# ASP.NET MultiView by ID?

Tags: asp.net, multiview

Is there a way to set the active view in a MultiView by ID rather than by index?

Something like this?

```
multiviewProgress.Views["step3"].SetToActiveView();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you can just do something like this:

```
 myMultiView.SetActiveView(nameOfView);
```

where nameOfView is the ID given at design time.  This [example](http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/sys/web/ui/webcontrols/MultiViewClassSetActiveView.aspx) shows you how to do it.